On the topic of letter grids
You are locked in a room, and are given this grid of letters:










W
U
S


Z
N
Q


A
K
J


C
F
I



The only thing on the door is a direction lock (enter in the code by up/down/left/right). There is nothing else of interest in the room. What is the code to the lock?
Hint:

 

Puzzle attribution: myself

It is far too early to give a hint. I think the hint makes the puzzle too easy.

Thankyou for the feedback, what is a good rough timeframe for hints?

24 hours for a hint

There is never a prescribed limit for hints though - I personally encourage publishing hints alongside the question as it makes puzzles more accessible for newer solvers while still allowing experienced solvers to have a challenge by ignoring the hints.

If you find hints make the puzzle too easy Benjamin, perhaps you should ignore them the next time one is published and try to solve it without them.

@Klumpy7, welcome to PSE! if you don't mind some feedback: in this case the hint made it very easy, but on the other hand, the hint was necessary. How else could the solver get confirmation what the solution was? A solution could be for example 'SUN' (topright: left, down). It's not told you need each letter. Let the solver know that he is on the right path, and that he is sure once he got a solution.

You should go:

 down, right, right, up, left, up, right, up, left, left, down

This is because:

 It creates the letter sequence ACFIJKNQSUWZ, which is all the letters arranged in alphabetical order!

The hint refers to

 how the Amazon logo features an arrow that goes from A to Z, like the alphabetical order!


TIL why the arrow is there on the Amazon logo

@DanDan面 it also features as a smiley with the 'a' s featuring somewhat as eyes. Not sure if this was intended though...
